# @Delete returns HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception

Hi i am trying to delect some entities from database, but when i use @Delete i get error in browsers, but Get is working. I am using hibernate JPA

Here are my code samples

@Entity

```
package pl.test.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
public class Mestechnologygroup {
    private Integer idTechnologyGroup;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Integer number;
    private Collection<Mestechnology> mestechnologiesByIdTechnologyGroup;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idTechnologyGroup")
    public Integer getIdTechnologyGroup() {
        return idTechnologyGroup;
    }

    public void setIdTechnologyGroup(Integer idTechnologyGroup) {
        this.idTechnologyGroup = idTechnologyGroup;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Number")
    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Mestechnologygroup that = (Mestechnologygroup) o;

        if (idTechnologyGroup != null ? !idTechnologyGroup.equals(that.idTechnologyGroup) : that.idTechnologyGroup != null)
            return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(that.name) : that.name != null) return false;
        if (description != null ? !description.equals(that.description) : that.description != null) return false;
        if (number != null ? !number.equals(that.number) : that.number != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = idTechnologyGroup != null ? idTechnologyGroup.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (description != null ? description.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (number != null ? number.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mestechnologygroupByIdTechnologyGroup")
    public Collection<Mestechnology> getMestechnologiesByIdTechnologyGroup() {
        return mestechnologiesByIdTechnologyGroup;
    }

    public void setMestechnologiesByIdTechnologyGroup(Collection<Mestechnology> mestechnologiesByIdTechnologyGroup) {
        this.mestechnologiesByIdTechnologyGroup = mestechnologiesByIdTechnologyGroup;
    }
}
```

presistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="testPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>pl.test.model.Mesattachmentoperation</class>
        <class>pl.test.model.Mesattachmenttechnology</class>
        <class>pl.test.model.Mesoperation</class>
        <class>pl.test.model.Mesoperationdictionary</class>
        <class>pl.test.model.Mesoperationstate</class>
        <class>pl.test.model.Mesproduct</class>
        <class>pl.test.model.Mesproducttype</class>
        <class>pl.test.model.Mesproductxoperation</class>
        <class>pl.test.model.Mesresource</class>
        <class>pl.test.model.Mesresourcexoperation</class>
        <class>pl.test.model.Mestechnology</class>
        <class>pl.test.model.Mestechnologygroup</class>
        <class>pl.test.model.Mesusers</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mes"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="xxxx"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Repository with method

```
package pl.test.repo;

import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;
import pl.test.model.Mestechnologygroup;
import pl.test.model.Mesusers;


import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

import static javax.transaction.Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED;
import static javax.transaction.Transactional.TxType.SUPPORTS;

@Transactional(SUPPORTS)
public class TechnologyGroupRepo {

    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU");
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    public Mestechnologygroup find(@NotNull Integer id) {
        return em.find(Mestechnologygroup.class, id);
    }

    public List<Mestechnologygroup> findAll() {
        TypedQuery<Mestechnologygroup> query = em.createQuery("from Mestechnologygroup ", Mestechnologygroup.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Transactional(REQUIRED)
    public void delete(@NotNull Integer id) {
        em.remove(em.getReference(Mestechnologygroup.class, id));
    }
}
```

here i use @Delete

```
package pl.test.rest;


import pl.test.model.Mestechnologygroup;
import pl.test.repo.TechnologyGroupRepo;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import java.util.List;

import static javax.transaction.Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED;
import static javax.transaction.Transactional.TxType.SUPPORTS;
import static javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;
@Path("/tg")
public class TechnologyGroupEndpoint{

        @Inject
        private TechnologyGroupRepo technologyGroupRepo;

        @GET
        @Path("/{id : \\d+}")
        @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response getBook(@PathParam("id") @Min(1) Integer id) {
            Mestechnologygroup mestechnologygroup = technologyGroupRepo.find(id);

            if (mestechnologygroup == null)
                return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();

            return Response.ok(mestechnologygroup).build();
        }

        @DELETE
        @Path("/d/{id : \\d+}")
        public Response deleteBook(@PathParam("id") @Min(1) Integer id) {
            technologyGroupRepo.delete(id);
            return Response.noContent().build();
        }

        @GET
        @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response getBooks() {
            List<Mestechnologygroup> mestechnologygroups = technologyGroupRepo.findAll();

            if (mestechnologygroups.size() == 0)
                return Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT).build();

            return Response.ok(mestechnologygroups).build();
        }


}
```

I revice that response in Google chrome
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2JFe.png)

I would appreciate any help :) Thanks in advance;)

Comment: you cannot do in a browser a DELETE operation. You need a rest client (curl, wget, Postman, Insomnia, integration test). When you access it in a browser, you are basically doing a GET

Comment: Ok, i didnt know about that i will read about it, thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*@Delete i get error in browsers, but Get is working.*

When you hit url on browser, it takes as GET request.

you can not make any other request than GET by browser, so GET works.

Try using http client tool like postman etc. or curl.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are facing is because a browser url is always accessed via GET http method. You cannot do for other http methods.

In order to test your DELETE endpoint, you have to do it using a REST client.

A few examples of rest clients: command line: `curl`, `wget`. With GUI: `Postman`, `Insomnia`.

An example of doing this from the command line:

```
curl -X DELETE "http://localhost:8080/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT/resources/tg/d/22"
```